# Application is crashing with different type of Exception

Tags: iphone, nsmutablearray

Hello I am taking records from core data entity and displaying it in tableview. 
My app is crashing when I view records and coming back but, not all time.
Here is my code

//load existing lyrics

```
- (void)loadLyricsForSong {
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfLyrics = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[song.songLyrics  allObjects]];
        NSSortDescriptor *nameDescriptor  = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"startTime" ascending:YES];//name wise sorting in asecending order

        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nameDescriptor,nil];
        [arrayOfLyrics sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];


        [self setLyricsArray:arrayOfLyrics];//setting mutable array with places
        [nameDescriptor release];
        [sortDescriptors release]; //releasing objects
        [arrayOfLyrics release];
        [self.tableView reloadData]; 

    }
```

I am calling this loadLyricsForSong method on viewWillAppear. and released lyricsArray in Dealloc method..

And exceptions are

```
> *** -[UITouchData retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5da0860
> *** -[NSConcreteNotification retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5d919b0
> *** -[CFArray retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x5b47d30
```

Please help..
Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does your `@property` declaration for `lyricsArray` look like?  If it is set to `assign` and not `retain` then this code will cause a crash.  Ensure that it is set to `retain`.

Comment: Also, Google for information on enabling `NSZombies`, as this lets you keep at least some information on deallocated objects.  It makes your app consume more memory, though, and should be turned off for your production release.

Comment: @property (nonatomic,retain)NSMutableArray *lyricsArray;

Comment: NSMutableArray *arrayOfLyrics = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[song.songLyrics  allObjects]] retain];
 I use like this and app is not crashing but  leaking at this line 100%

Comment: just a coding suggestion, why do you alloc and init all these objects if you stop using it at the end of the method, when you could just use the class methods to create an autoreleased version.

Comment: It looks like you're overreleasing `lyricsArray` *somewhere*.  Check elsewhere within your code.  In your `dealloc` method, you only need to call `self.lyricsArray = nil;` ... do not also call `[lyricsArray release]` as assigning to nil has this effect when using `self.`.